# Where are 70 verses attributed to Nagarjuna from?

Tags: mulamadhyamakakarika

Where are the 70 verses of Nagarjuna from?  Is it from Mulamukhyamakakarika or elsewhere? Is it a reconstruction of other works or original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a separate work altogether. You can find an English translation of it online- one of them goes by the title - Nagarjuna's Seventy Stanzas: A Buddhist Psychology of Emptiness.

It is not from Mulamadhyamakakarika or any other work of Nagarjuna or anyone else. Not a reconstructed work.

Comment: just in case someone else stumbles upon this question i would add the transliterated name of the verses is *Sunyatasaptati*

Comment: also the version i downloaded - exactly 70 verses - was by a Dr. Jay Garfield, but there is another version of 73 verses that seems more authentic.